# @KafkaListener vs ConsumerFactory groupId

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I followed "[Intro to Apache Kafka with Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-kafka)" tutorial by baeldung.com.
I set up a `KafkaConsumerConfig` class with the `kafkaConsumerFactory` method:

```java
private ConsumerFactory<String, String> kafkaConsumerFactory(String groupId) {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    ...
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    ...
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}
```

and two "custom" factories:

```java
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> fooKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    return kafkaListenerContainerFactory("foo");
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> barKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    return kafkaListenerContainerFactory("bar");
}
```

In the `MessageListener` class, instead I used `@KafkaListener` annotation to register consumers with the given `groupId` to listen on a topic:

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "${message.topic.name}", groupId = "foo", containerFactory = "fooKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void listenGroupFoo(String message) {
    System.out.println("Received Message in group 'foo': " + message);
    ...
}

@KafkaListener(topics = "${message.topic.name}", groupId = "bar", containerFactory = "barKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void listenGroupBar(String message) {
    System.out.println("Received Message in group 'bar': " + message);
    ...
}
```

In this way there are two group of consumers, the ones having groupId "foo" and the ones having groupId "bar".

Now if I change container factory for the "foo" consumers from `fooKafkaListenerContainerFactory` to `barKafkaListenerContainerFactory` in this way

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "${message.topic.name}", groupId = "foo", containerFactory = "barKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void listenGroupFoo(String message) {
    ...
}
```

It seems an incompatibility between `groupId` of `KafkaListener` and `groupId` of container factory but nothing changes.
So, what I'm trying to understand is what `props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);`property does and why it seem is not considered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The factory `groupId` is a default which is only used if there is no `groupId` (or `id`) on the `@KafkaListener`.

In early versions, it was only possible to set the groupId on the factory, which meant you needed a separate factory for each listener if different groups are needed, which defeats the idea of a factory that can be used for multiple listeners.

See the javadocs...

```java
/**
 * Override the {@code group.id} property for the consumer factory with this value
 * for this listener only.
 * <p>SpEL {@code #{...}} and property place holders {@code ${...}} are supported.
 * @return the group id.
 * @since 1.3
 */
String groupId() default "";

/**
 * When {@link #groupId() groupId} is not provided, use the {@link #id() id} (if
 * provided) as the {@code group.id} property for the consumer. Set to false, to use
 * the {@code group.id} from the consumer factory.
 * @return false to disable.
 * @since 1.3
 */
boolean idIsGroup() default true;
```